# AND/OR logic with .filter()

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, filtering

I am trying to create a product grid filtering system. By calling `.filter()` on a JSON object I get the results I'm looking for.

```
const filteredProducts = allProducts.filter((a) => {
  // return brown or blue products in with omnis tag
  const prodTags = a.tags;
  return (
    prodTags.includes('brown') && prodTags.includes('single-eye') && prodTags.includes('happy') ||
    prodTags.includes('brown') && prodTags.includes('single-eye') && prodTags.includes('angry') ||
    prodTags.includes('brown') && prodTags.includes('two-eyes') && prodTags.includes('happy') ||
    prodTags.includes('brown') && prodTags.includes('two-eyes') && prodTags.includes('angry') ||
    prodTags.includes('blue') && prodTags.includes('single-eye') && prodTags.includes('happy') ||
    prodTags.includes('blue') && prodTags.includes('single-eye') && prodTags.includes('angry') ||
    prodTags.includes('blue') && prodTags.includes('two-eyes') && prodTags.includes('happy') ||
    prodTags.includes('blue') && prodTags.includes('two-eyes') && prodTags.includes('angry')
  );
});
```

I am having trouble thinking of a way to make this dynamic. I cant seem to create a function that can generate this logic automatically for any number of tags.

I have a filtering system that looks like this (~ being the current selected ones):

```
-----------
Colors:
-----------
~ brown
gray
~ blue
pink


-----------
Eyes:
-----------
~ single-eye
~ two-eyes


-----------
Emotion:
-----------
~ happy
~ angry
sad
```

The logic between categories is AND. The logic between values of a category is OR. I have a function setup that creates a cartesian product array. the selected filters array would look like this:

```
[
    ['brown', 'single-eye', 'angry'],
    ['brown', 'single-eye', 'happy'],
    ['brown', 'two-eyes', 'angry'],
    ['brown', 'two-eyes', 'happy'],
    ['blue', 'single-eye', 'angry'],
    ['blue', 'single-eye', 'happy'],
    ['blue', 'two-eyes', 'angry'],
    ['blue', 'two-eyes', 'happy']
]
```

This is where I am stuck. I cannot seem to figure out a way to dynamically integrate this generated array within `.filter()` and use || and && accordingly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not certain what expected result is? Can you include input array at Question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both other answers look right. In addition to what is already suggested, I would also use `Array.every` so that the function doesn't depend on the length of each row.

```
const cart = [
    ['brown', 'single-eye', 'angry'],
    ['brown', 'single-eye', 'happy'],
    ['brown', 'two-eyes', 'angry'],
    ['brown', 'two-eyes', 'happy'],
    ['blue', 'single-eye', 'angry'],
    ['blue', 'single-eye', 'happy'],
    ['blue', 'two-eyes', 'angry'],
    ['blue', 'two-eyes', 'happy']
  ];

const filteredProducts = allProducts.filter((a) => {
  const prodTags = a.tags;

  return cart.some((row) => {
    return row.every((element) => {
      return prodTags.includes(element);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Good suggestion.

Comment: Awesome! a function that doesnt depend on the length of the row, is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you for that small improvement and thank you  @RickHitchcock for your original solution. You guys are awesome!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**Array.prototype.some()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) on your Cartesian product array to make sure at least one of the conditions is met:

```
const filteredProducts = allProducts.filter((a) => {
  const prodTags = a.tags,
        cart = [
                ['brown', 'single-eye', 'angry'],
                ['brown', 'single-eye', 'happy'],
                ['brown', 'two-eyes', 'angry'],
                ['brown', 'two-eyes', 'happy'],
                ['blue', 'single-eye', 'angry'],
                ['blue', 'single-eye', 'happy'],
                ['blue', 'two-eyes', 'angry'],
                ['blue', 'two-eyes', 'happy']
               ];

  return cart.some((e) => {
    return progTags.includes(e[0]) && progTags.includes(e[1]) && progTags.includes(e[2]);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array with the grouped item and iterate with a check.

```js
var allProducts = [{ foo: 1, tags: ['abc', 'def'] }, { foo: 2, tags: ['blue', 'two-eyes', 'happy'] }],
    groups = [['brown', 'blue'], ['single-eye', 'two-eyes'], ['angry', 'happy']],
    filteredProducts = allProducts.filter(product => groups.every(group => group.some(item => product.tags.includes(item))));

console.log(filteredProducts);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The expected generated logic means that any particular row in your array, if resulting in `true`, would be the last row needed to be computed. My approach would be to do a `for` loop that breaks when a particular row returns `true`. If no row results in `true`, fall back to `false`:

```
var filtersArray = [
  ['brown', 'single-eye', 'angry'],
  ['brown', 'single-eye', 'happy'],
  ['brown', 'two-eyes', 'angry'],
  ['brown', 'two-eyes', 'happy'],
  ['blue', 'single-eye', 'angry'],
  ['blue', 'single-eye', 'happy'],
  ['blue', 'two-eyes', 'angry'],
  ['blue', 'two-eyes', 'happy']
];


const filteredProducts = allProducts.filter((a) => {
  // return brown or blue products in with omnis tag
  const prodTags = a.tags;

  for (var i = 0; i < filtersArray.length; i++) {
    let color = filtersArray[i][0];
    let count = filtersArray[i][1];
    let emotion = filtersArray[i][2];

    if (prodTags.includes(color) && prodTags.includes(count) && prodTags.includes(emotion)) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
)};
```